# Move data from custom XML file to ArrayList AndroidStudio

Tags: java, android, xml, arraylist

I have this a class with these attributes

```
private String placa;
private String marca;
private String color;
private Date FecFac;
private Double costo;
private Boolean matriculado;
```

And this XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<datos>
<Vehiculo>
    <placa>PBQ-1234</placa>
    <marca>Ferrari</marca>
    <FecFac>2017-01-01</FecFac>>
    <costo>68570</costo>
    <matriculado>Si</matriculado>
    <color>Otro</color>
</Vehiculo>

<Vehiculo>
    <placa>PCD-2879</placa>
    <marca>Honda</marca>
    <FecFac>2015-05-23</FecFac>>
    <costo>34690</costo>
    <matriculado>No</matriculado>
    <color>Blanco</color>
</Vehiculo>
</datos>
```

The XML file is saved under res/xml under the name datos.xml

I need to put the data in that XML file to an ArrayList, question is how? I've been messing around with XStream but I'm still not sure how to call the XML file in question.

How would the data validation work too? Like data and double values work.

Also I need to later rewrite over that XML file, is it's location an issue?

Answer (score 0):

Use [XmlPullParser](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html).

The parser allows you to, well, parse the XML. It will ensure the XML is well formed. If you are applying semantics on top of that, you'll need to implement them yourself (data validation, etc).

You cannot overwrite values in `res`. That winds up as binary data in your APK. If you need to write the XML, you'll have to leave the original in place and store your XML somewhere else. The "where" is up to you, and not knowing what you are doing, I can only direct you to this to make up your own mind:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: But how do I use it for my example? I've already found that but reading android's site confuses me more than anything.

Comment: There's an example right there on the page I linked.